# how to extract elements of a sparse matrix?

Tags: matlab, extract, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix:

```
 A=


  (14,13)      0.5286
  (15,14)      0.6781
  (16,15)      0.5683
  (17,16)      1.2773
  (18,17)      1.0502
  (19,18)      0.4966
  (21,19)      0.9951
  (21,20)      0.4522
  (22,21)      0.8507
  (23,22)      1.0727
  (24,23)      0.8288
  (25,24)      0.5811
  (26,25)      0.8235
  (28,26)      1.5128
  (30,28)      0.7966
  (30,29)      0.6363
  (31,29)      0.8254
  (32,31)      0.8573
  (33,32)      1.0753
```

that is result of a minimum spanning tree. now I want to extract `13,14,15,...26,28,29,...33`.
as seen 27 is not between numbers. so `pred` give:   `13    14    15    16    17    18    19    21    22    23    24    25    26    28    29    30    31    32` that 20 and 33 is not.
how can I extract total of numbers that say in top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[ii jj] = find(A);
answer = unique([ii(:); jj(:)]);
```

should do it.

Note that the `find` command with two outputs gives you the row and column index of all nonzero elements. Since you have a minimum spanning tree, each number you care about needs to occur at least once in the row or column (for example your matrix never has the number `29` in the first index, but it occurs in the second).

The `unique` function makes sure that each number that occurs is only represented once.